# CSS3 prevent content overflowing flexbox

Tags: html, css, webkit

I'm trying to put a border around an existing page to essentially "frame" the content. 
I've been trying to use webkit's flexbox because it's flex property seems to be the best for the job, but I can't get it to work when the content overflows the window size. Ideally i'd like it to scroll within the frame. What I've got so far is at http://cssdesk.com/

I only really need it to work in Chrome Canary so i'm not worried about compatiblity issues, just getting it to work. Any hints, or has this been done somewhere else I can copy?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing an explicit `width` and `height` and set `overflow:auto`